Delphi iTask generates out of memory error at random times
I have to process an specific code in 5 different intervals. Each code is very similar differing just some parameters from each other.  To accomplish this job I created an array of iTask where the number of tasks is according the number of interval (5 in my example).
I created a function "CreateiTask" which returns the iTask. This function has two Tstrings parameters that are populated inside the function.
I also created a procedure CreateArrayofiTask which create the array of iTask based on the size of the parameter pInterval.
Although it seems bth methods were created accordingly, the main program is presenting an access violation randomically.  I cannot figure out what is wrong and how to fix it.
Here is the complete code :
unit UntArrayofiTask;
interface

Uses
     System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Threading;

TYPE
    ArriTask     = array of iTask;
    TArrString   = array of string;


Function   CreateiTask ( pInterval_A     : string;
                         pParamrequest_A : TStrings;
                         pResults_A      : TStrings ) : iTask;

Procedure  CreateArrayofiTask ( pInterval : Tarray<string>;
                            pParamrequest : TStrings; pResults : TStrings);


implementation


Function CreateiTask ( pInterval_A     : string;
                       pParamrequest_A : TStrings;
                       pResults_A      : TStrings ) : iTask;
begin
     RESULT := TTask.Create
             (
               procedure
               var
                 lnum : integer;
                 lstr : string;
               begin
                    pResults_A.Add('Intervalo: ' + pInterval_A);

                    for lnum:=0 to pParamrequest_A.Count-1 do
                        pResults_A.Add(pParamrequest_A[lnum]);

                    pResults_A.Add('-------------------------------');
               end
            );
end;

Procedure CreateArrayofiTask ( pInterval : Tarray<string>;
                               pParamrequest : Tstrings; pResults : TStrings);
var
   lArrayTask          : array of iTask;
   idxinterval,lsize  : byte;
begin
     lsize := Length(pInterval);
     SetLength(lArrayTask,lSize);
     for idxinterval := Low(lArrayTask) to High(lArrayTask) do
     begin
          lArrayTask[idxinterval]:= CreateiTask ( pInterval[idxinterval],pParamrequest,pResults);
          lArrayTask[idxinterval].Start;
     end;
     TTask.WaitForAll(lArrayTask);
end;

end.

an this is the main program - VCL Program
unit FRMThreadArrayiTask;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,

  UntArrayofiTask;

type
  TFormArrayTask = class(TForm)
    BTRunTasks: TButton;
    MemoResults: TMemo;
    LBoxInterval: TListBox;
    EdtExecucao: TEdit;
    LBExecucao: TLabel;
    MemoIterations: TMemo;
    LBParameter: TLabel;
    LBResults: TLabel;
    LBResultIteration: TLabel;
    procedure BTRunTasksClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormArrayTask: TFormArrayTask;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormArrayTask.BTRunTasksClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   idx,iteration    : byte;
   larrstrinterval  : Tarray<string>;
   lparam        : Tstrings;
   lresults      : Tstrings;
   ldtin,ldtfin  : TDateTime;
begin
     ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

     memoResults.Clear;
     memoIterations.Lines.Clear;

     //Run n times to get the error happen
     for iteration := 1 to  StrToint(EdtExecucao.text) do
     BEGIN
           SetLength(larrstrinterval,LBoxInterval.Items.Count);
           lparam   := Tstringlist.Create;
           lresults := Tstringlist.Create;
           TRY
               memoResults.lines.Text :='';

               lParam.AddPair('StartTime',FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD''T''hh:nn:ss',strToDate('11/01/2021')));
               lParam.AddPair('EndTime'  ,FormatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD''T''hh:nn:ss',strToDate('11/01/2021')));
               lParam.AddPair('Location','SP');

               //Add the interval values ( 'DAILY','WEEKLY','MONTLHY','QUARTERLY','ANNUAL')
               for idx := 0 to LBoxInterval.Items.Count-1 do
               begin
                    larrstrinterval[idx] := LBoxInterval.Items[idx];
               end;

               //Create an iTask array with n intervals and run each TTask
               CreateArrayofiTask(larrstrinterval,lparam,lresults);

               memoResults.lines.Text := lresults.text;
           FINALLY
                lparam.Free;
                lresults.Free;
           END;
           memoIterations.Lines.Add('Iterarion # : ' + iteration.ToString) ;
     END;

end;

end.

When run this code for 5 or more times some error occur :

It also frozen sometimes :

Is there anything wrong with the declaration of iTask array of the function?
Is there anything wrong with the parameters passed through the function and procedure to the main program?
Where is the problem of this code ?
Thanks for your help!

The problem is that you use the variable (TStringList) lResults from all the different tasks (threads) without protecting against simultaneous access.
The simultaneous access messes up TStringList's internal memory reallocation.
Fix it by adding a critical section, like this - it makes sure that only one task (thread) at a time can modify the stringlist:
uses
  System.SyncObjs;

var
  CritSect: TCriticalSection;  // Global variable

Function CreateiTask ( pInterval_A     : string;
                       pParamrequest_A : TStrings;
                       pResults_A      : TStrings ) : iTask;
begin
     RESULT := TTask.Create
             (
               procedure
               var
                 lnum : integer;
                 lstr : string;
               begin
                    CritSect.Acquire;  // <------------- ADDED LINE
                    try
                      pResults_A.Add('Intervalo: ' + pInterval_A);

                      for lnum:=0 to pParamrequest_A.Count-1 do
                          pResults_A.Add(pParamrequest_A[lnum]);

                      pResults_A.Add('-------------------------------');
                    finally
                      CritSect.Release;  // <------------- ADDED LINE
                    end;
               end
            );
end;

initialization
  CritSect := TCriticalSection.Create;
finalization
  CritSect.Free;
end.

In this example, since modifying the stringlist is all the task does, this critical section really destroys the multi-threading (because all the tasks will get forced to work in sequence). But in a more realistic case, which I'm sure you have, then the task could do real "calculations" and only then, at the end, add the result to lResults - and only that part should be inside the critical section.
(Not strictly necessary, but the code would benefit, from a human perspective, from more adherence to code formatting standards: types normally start with the prefix T in Object Pascal, keywords are usually all lowercase (type, begin, end), spaces are usually not used that generously - but it works also without those adjustments.)

Thanks a lot for the solution, explanations and recommendations as well.  I understood your solution and I'll try it asap.  Before your reply I made a test which worked fine too.  I changed the parameter pResults to an array of Tstrings and so, each task uses it's own instance of Tstrings. The array size is also the number of TTasks created.   Please take a look at this changed code and let me know your opinion.  Thks.

Yes, your change also makes it work. After that change, two tasks no longer access the same stringlist. (Your main procedure will need to gather up all the results, of course.) I think your solution is better than mine - it's nice in general if the tasks work on completely separate pieces of memory (and then you combine it all to the final end result afterwards).

Great @Matthias B! Thanks for your conclusions and valuable help!

Code changed to use an array of Tstrigns, each Tstring runs in specific TTask.
  Function CreateiTask ( pInterval_A     : string;
                           pParamrequest_A : TStrings;
                           pResults_A      : TStrings ) : iTask;
    begin
         RESULT := TTask.Create
                 (
                   procedure
                   var
                     lnum : integer;
                     lstr : string;
                   begin
                        pResults_A.Add('-------------------------------');
                        pResults_A.Add('TASK Intervalo: ' + pInterval_A);
                        pResults_A.Add('-------------------------------');
    
                        for lnum:=0 to pParamrequest_A.Count-1 do
                            pResults_A.Add(pParamrequest_A[lnum]);
    
                        pResults_A.Add('************************************');
                   end
                );
    end;
    
    
    Procedure CreateArrayofiTask ( pInterval : Tarray<string>;
                                   var pParamrequest :array of TStrings; var pResults : array of TStrings);
    var
       lArrayTask          : array of iTask;
       idxinterval,lsize  : byte;
    begin
         lsize := Length(pInterval);
         SetLength(lArrayTask,lSize);
         for idxinterval := Low(lArrayTask) to High(lArrayTask) do
         begin
              // Add another parameter
              pParamrequest[idxinterval].AddPair('Interval parameter',pInterval[idxinterval]);
    
              pResults[idxinterval]  := Tstringlist.Create;

              lArrayTask[idxinterval]:= 
               CreateiTask ( 
                             pInterval[idxinterval],
                             pParamrequest[idxinterval],
                             pResults[idxinterval] 
                            );
              lArrayTask[idxinterval].Start;
         end;
         TTask.WaitForAll(lArrayTask);
    end;

